# 'cdk' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying my hands with `AWS CDK` & as the first step, I need to install `cdk` & as per below link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html

I tried installing the same

Steps.

1. `node --version` => v15.14.0
2. `npm --version  => 7.11.2`
3. `aws -version` => aws-cli/2.2.1 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off`
4. `npm -g install typescript`
5. `aws configure` (AWS AccessKey, Secret,Region)
6. `npm -g install aws-cdk`

Now closed all the cmd instances & ran

```
cdk --version
```

this throws the below error

> 'cdk' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Then I added the below path of cdk to environment variable

> C:\Users\kgn-dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\bin\cdk

still the same issue.

How do I get **cdk** command running?

*I am using Windows 10*

Comment: When you add something to the PATH, it is a directory, not a file.

Answer (score 5):

try to add the following path to the environment variable

```
C:\Users\kgn-dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\bin
```

Comment: Yes, it worked !

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `aws-cdk` directory has been successfully created under this path.

```
C:\Users\kgn-dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

If the `aws-cdk` directory is not in this path, finding where it is and saving its location to the path in the environment variables should solve it.

Check in: `C:\Users\kgn-dev\AppData\Local\npm`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67479298/19807807) by @kayuapi_my you can try adding the following path to the environment variables.

> C:\Users\mzain\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\bin

But if this does not work, or you are unable to locate the path then you can install aws-cdk globally.

> npm install -g aws-cdk

The second solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and doing the below steps solves it.

1: upgrade npm : npm install -g npm

2: uninstall aws-CDK: npm uninstall -g aws-cdk

3: install it: npm install -g aws-cdk

hope this will help you.